# IIS6 Problems with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have a ASP.NET MVC page. I Configured a IIS Website and added the additonal H:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll.

my Directory Structure is like that

```
/
../App_data/
../bin/
../Content/
../Properties/
../Scripts/
../Views/
../Default.aspx
../Global.asax
../Web.config
```

My page is configured to port 9090.

If i try to access the page i get the "default" Page. But if i try to access any other page than the //myServer:9090  like //myServer:9090/home (which is the default method in my HomeController) i get a "page not found" error page.

For me it looks like he does'nt execute the assambly. In the Debbuging Server all runs nice.

What could be the Problem?

P.S: If i forgort something pls ask for! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [nice post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) explaining how to configure ASP.NET MVC to run on IIS6 using extensionless routes.

Comment: thanks a lot, but my development machine has no direct access to the server.

Comment: And what do you expect us to do about this? Configure the server for you? There are steps that you need to perform on the server to make this work.

Comment: but i did :S and i am realy confused about my error. The Server runs and the Default page loads but nothing else. How could that be?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [page](http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx).  You have to do different things to IIS to get MVC to run based upon what version of IIS you are using.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i allready have implemented exact the example for iis 6 (in Global.asax) :(. I have had a configuration a week ago on the iis which already worked. But now i doesn't and i realy can't find the crap

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was that i use a 64BIT Server so i had to unclick "confirm that file exists"